# Can Blazor datagrid be filtered by an async func?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, filter, grid, blazor

I am working on a Blazor NET 5 project.
I am displaying data in a Grid (MudTable), and understand how to filter it with an attribute
Filter="new Func<Dataset, bool>(Search)"
where Search is

```
private bool Search(Dataset dataset)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString)) return true;
        if (dataset.name.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But now I have to filter by the content of data which is the response of an async method.
My Search method would then be something like

```
private async Task <bool> Search(Dataset dataset)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString)) return true;
        if (dataset.name.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var response = await Http.GetAsync($"api/Files/metadata/Download?directory={dataset.Name}");
            if response.metadata.descr != "" return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Is this possible to still use Func attribute as a filter or do I have to find another way?

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs website there is a way:

https://mudblazor.com/api/table

ServerData  Func<TableState, Task<TableData>>
Supply an async function which (re)loads filtered, paginated and sorted data from server. Table will await this func and update based on the returned TableData. Used only with ServerData